# android database insert problem

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to take the datas from the edittext and then insert it into the sqlite.
now i am doing like

```
ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("Name",name);
    value.put("id", password);
    value.put("email",email);
db.insert("EMP",null,value);
```

**Name,password and email** are the variables,but this is not working as no data is being entered into the table.

Any solutions please.

Comment: first check that the table is created or not.

Comment: yep the table in created with three columns name,id and email.:-)

Comment: yes, and then capture the returnvalue of db.insert

Comment: its returning 7.what it means.....!

Comment: What is the issue? is the row inserted or does it return an error while writing to db? Do you have a null check on your edittext vars?

Comment: no but iam not entering any null value.i like to post the source code below

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK. The insert function returns the id of the newly created row. You could test that to check whether the call was successful. A value of -1 indicates that an error occurred.

I am a bit concerned that you have a field called id, especially one that is not numeric. It should be OK, but _id is reserved for the row id, and you definitely do not want to go messing with that.

Comment: Actually error was in sql connection code.Thanx for ur help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

please try to pass _id as the second parameter of insert() instead of null.

the following code works fine in my program.

```
dbSqlite.insert(tableName, DataBaseConstant.FIELD_ID,
                initialValues);
```

hope can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: k i got the answer for this.actually error was in sql connection.i was using two classes to reterieve the same table.in that i was individually using the code SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("bivin.db",SQliteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSORY,null) which i resolved it with SQLiteOpenHelper class.Thanx for ur precious help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these three lines

```
    db.setVersion(1);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
```

before your db.insert line.

Answer (score -1):

if db.insert() return -1 an error occurred.
you must check

1. fields exist in sqlite datatbase.
2. foreign keys are correct.
3. unique fields are correct.
4. not null fields are correct.
5. if id is AUTOINCREMENT you do not need to fill it.